# Pandas - fast DataFrame transformation for neural nets ("gausrank")

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transformation, ranking

Firstly, thank you for helping

I have large pandas DataFrame and I need fast "rank" transformation for each column:

1] if column is only 0-1, do nothing

2] else (for each column):

a] find unique values in the column

b] sort them

c] for each element of the column replace its value with the position in sort-unique "ranking" list

optional:

d] transform this new values to interval [-0.99, 0.99]

e] apply scipy.special.erfinv to each element (to get "normal" like distribution)

How can I do this with Pandas, when need to take care about speed..

Thanx

Comment: "if column is only 0-1".  Is this "only floats in interval [0 to 1]" or "only 0s and 1s"?

Comment: it is only binary 0 or 1

Answer (score 4):

Getting columns containing only `0` or `1`:

```
columns_to_handle = (~df.isin([0,1])).any()
```

Converting column type to categorical conveniently handles steps a, b and c:

```
df.some_column.astype('category').cat.codes
```

Unfortunately this does seem to require a loop (through `apply`) over the columns, but if you don't have too many columns this should still be reasonably fast.

Rescaling can just be done by subtracting the minimum and dividing by the maximum for each column. However, as the minimum of each column is 0 already the first step is redundant.

Scipy's `erfinv` can just take a dataframe as input. However, the values must be between `-1` and `1`, *exclusive*. So the range will be `epsilon` smaller.

#### Combining it all

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.special import erfinv

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [['a', 10, 0],
     ['b', 11, 1],
     ['c',  9, 0],
     ['d', 12, 1]],
    columns=['val1', 'val2', 'val3']
)

columns_to_handle = (~df.isin([0, 1])).any()

intermediate = df.loc[:, columns_to_handle].apply(lambda x: x.astype('category').cat.codes)

epsilon = 0.0001

# intermediate -= intermediate.min() # the minimum is 0 for every column already
intermediate /= intermediate.max()/(2-2*epsilon)
intermediate -= (1-epsilon)

intermediate = erfinv(intermediate)

result = pd.concat(
   [intermediate,
    df.loc[:, ~columns_to_handle]],
  axis=1)
```

`result` being the following dataframe:

```
       val1      val2  val3
0 -2.751064 -0.304538     0
1 -0.304538  0.304538     1
2  0.304538 -2.751064     0
3  2.751064  2.751064     1
```

Comment: this is perfect! exactly what I need, thank you very much